# Python: Using a loop to flatten a JSON in Snowpark (dynamically referring to different objects at the same level)

Tags: python, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two lists of values, both of which are the same length as the no. of rows in my Snowspark df. I want to use said lists to flatten the JSON column. I want to dynamically refer to different objects which are at the same level. This input enables flattening.

My thought was to use a loop to achieve this. Now, I will display a sample of both (2 items in each of the lists and the two corresponding rows in the df):

```
list_1 = ['plane', 'ship']
list_2 = ['flight_class', 'ship_cabin']
```

The two JSON rows:

[image]

[image]

I've tried a loop for the first list. However, it seems to overwrite the first up and thus, leave nulls:

```
for x in list:
    dataframe_return = dataframe.select(col("STREAMING_DATA")["transport"][x])
```

Does anyone know how to correct this so each item in the list is matched with one row (the corresponding one) in the df. I'll try and sort out the second list myself once I know how to handle the first.

This is the final desired output, using both lists:

[image]

Comment: You're overwriting `dataframe_return` each time through the loop. Please show what your desired result should be. I suspect you want each iteration to append to the result df.

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment, so you can format it.

Comment: It's also not clear what the JSON is. Is that supposed to be a list of objects? Then you need to iterate over it to find the one that has the desired transport.

Comment: `for item in json_list: if x in item['transport']: ...`

Comment: I've added the final desired output - using both lists. The JSON specifies the mode of transport, the class and the value. The paired value for transport can be different values (hence why I need a dynamic approach, as can the class type (ship or flight) and I also need that to get the value (upper lower etc). So I don't want to hard code 'ship' or 'flight' at that level, not 'ship_cabin' nor 'flight_class' at the other level.

Comment: So you have dictionaries in the original dataframe?

Comment: Yes. And yes, I'm overwriting the df everytime. can't work out how to configure the loop so it appends, rather than overwrites.

Comment: If you want to iterate over both lists, use `for transport, class in zip(list_1, list_2):`

Comment: Then you just want to select the rows of the df where `transport in row['STREAMING_DATA']['transport']`

Comment: But then I need to specify the transport type, which I don't want to hard code. I've tried this and still run into the same problem. As for a zip, not sure how to use that with a snowpark df. Isn't that just for connecting two datasets? For example, turning them into a tuples. Still unsure how to do the loop to actually get those values into the json.

Comment: You're not hard-coding it, it comes from the `transport` variable that gets it from `list_1`.

Comment: Unfortunately my pandas expertise is limited so I'm not sure how to do this in detail.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your support. I'm actually not using Pandas. Just base Python in Snowpark. Plan to put this into an AWS Lambda eventually, so I'm conscientious of memory issues.